# How to use markdown-it plugins options in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, markdown-it

I'm using `@nuxtjs/markdownit` to parse markdown files, I want to enable creating permanent links feature in `'markdown-it-anchor'` plugin, I used following code in `nuxt.config.js` but not working:

```
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/markdownit'
  ],
  markdownit: {
    preset: 'default',
    linkify: true,
    breaks: true,
    typographer: true,
    html: false,
    use: [
      'markdown-it-anchor',
      'markdown-it-attrs',
      'markdown-it-div',
      'markdown-it-toc-done-right',
      'markdown-it-emoji'
    ]
  },
  'markdown-it-anchor': {
    level: 1,
    // slugify: string => string,
    permalink: true,
    // renderPermalink: (slug, opts, state, permalink) => {},
    permalinkClass: 'header-anchor',
    permalinkSymbol: '¶',
    permalinkBefore: true
  },
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Self answering: I found the syntax in this [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vuejs/comments/ef88pl/nuxtjs_for_blogging_a_question_on_markdown_posts/)

```
markdownit: {
    preset: 'default',
    linkify: true,
    breaks: true,
    typographer: true,
    html: false,
    use: [
      [
        'markdown-it-anchor',
        {
          level: 1,
          // slugify: string => string,
          permalink: true,
          // renderPermalink: (slug, opts, state, permalink) => {},
          permalinkClass: 'header-anchor',
          permalinkSymbol: '¶',
          permalinkBefore: true
        }
      ],
      'markdown-it-attrs',
      'markdown-it-div',
      'markdown-it-toc-done-right',
      'markdown-it-emoji'
    ]
  },
```